# PHP in html creates white space

Tags: php, html

```
    <select id="selectedCountry">
<?php

        /*FETCH COUNTRY*/
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM countries";
        if($result2 = $conn -> query($sql2)) {
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                ?>
                
                    <option value="<?php echo strip_tags($row2['country_code']); ?>">
                        <?php echo strip_tags($row2['country_name']); ?>
                    </option>>

                <?php
            }
        }

?>
</select>
```

Inside the while loop there are empty lines and white space. I wrote that option in multiple lines to make it look better but its outputting the white space.

Is this what usually happens? If not then what is causing this here?

When I console.log the selected country name, it includes the whitespace.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var s = $("#selectedCountry" ).find(":selected").text();
console.log(s);
```

[my code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX1l8.png)

[whitespace visible in html source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAvxH.png)

[whitespace in country name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k76to.png)

Comment: Why do you use `strip_tags`? I think that was meant to be `htmlentities()` instead

Comment: You have empty lines and whitespaces in your code between `?>` and `<option` and between `</option>>` and `<?php`. You also have extra `>` after `</option>`

Comment: If you’re not OK with the whitespaces, you should use `?><option` and `</option><?php`.

Comment: yes it should be htmlentities()

Answer (score 0):

I've never actually cared about how pretty my source code is.  If you want to have complete control over the source code spacing, then one way is to print each option within php tags and manually add the newline (`\n`) character.  You can even add a tab (`\t`) before each option tag if you are so inclined.

If your values *actually* do have excess leading and trailing spaces, then just use `trim()`, but I am not completely convinced that this is the case.

Don't mix procedural with object-oriented mysqli syntax.  I recommend that you stay with object-oriented it is more concise and easier to work with.

The mysqli result is an iterable object -- you don't need to keep calling fetch functions.

Only select exactly what you intend to use from the database.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/W9NAf))

```
<select id="selectedCountry">
    <?php
    if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT country_code, country_name FROM countries")) {
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            printf(
                "\t<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>\n", 
                trim(htmlentities($row['country_code'])), 
                trim(htmlentities($row['country_name']))
            );
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the option in a single line. The white space will be gone.

It is ussual behaviour to create white spaces when writing it on multiple lines.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can remove those unwanted spaces using php native function `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $row2['country_name']);`

Here is complete code
$row2['country_name']

```
<select id="selectedCountry">
<?php
    /*FETCH COUNTRY*/
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM countries";
    if($result2 = $conn -> query($sql2)) {
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            //Clear the data from html and remove unwante scape
            $countryName = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($row2['country_code']));
            ?>               
                <option value="<?php echo $countryName; ?>">
                    <?php echo $countryName; ?>
                </option>>
            <?php
        }
    }

?>
</select>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Please never write "Hope this helps".  Of course you do, but it never needs to be said here.  There are no extra spaces in the countryName and you are ruining the data with that declaration.

Comment: Roger @mickmackusa